# How should I configure (JPA) my persistence.xml file if I could configure my hibernate.cfg.xml (Hibernate)?

Tags: hibernate

This is how my **hibernate.cfg.xml** look like. My program is working with this fine. I connected to a MySQL database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">mintaalkalmazas2</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <mapping resource="Kerdes.hbm.xml"/>
  <mapping resource="TestTable.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This would be the **persistence.xml**. I know it's not right configured yet. I would like to connect to the same MySQL database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
  <persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Todo</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"></property>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />

      <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
        value="database" />
    </properties>

  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I added these .jar files:

[image]

Comment: What do you want to be using? Eclipselik or Hibernate?

Comment: I want to use Hibernate

Answer (score 8):

This one will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="YOUR_PASSWORD"/>

            <!--Hibernate properties-->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

You can put your `XML Mappings` in `orm.xml` file, if you would like to have many mapping files you should attach them using `<mapping-file>` element in `<persistence-unit>`.

You can also not use mapping files and just annotate entities.

**update**

You should also have `Hibernate` and it persistence api on the classpath, if you are using maven then you should add following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is maybe good. (I'm working on localhost, and I don't have any password.)

Comment: I get an error in my project and don't know why. Maybe my persistence.xml is already good.

I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named todos
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
 at Main.main(Main.java:15)


This line in Main.java is the cause:

    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

Comment: what's the value of `PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME`? Does it fit one in `persistence.xml`? Do you have `Hibernate` and `JPA` libraries on your classpath?

Comment: private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "todos";

I think it should fit to his line in persistence.xml:
<persistence-unit name="todos" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

Comment: Sorry, I want to edit my question and I edited your answer. I didn't want to edit your answer

Comment: I added hibernate jar files. I made a printscreen about it. I get the same error cause of the same line

Comment: @Kroy, remove the `Eclipselink` jar from your libs since you want to use `Hibernate` and **put `persistence.xml` file under `META-INF` directory**